# jList not displaying data in specific case

Tags: java, jlist

In my program, I have a jList and I can add, delete, modify items in this Jlist.
My problem is, if I click on my add button before selecting an item in my jList, the items inside the jList disapear. (only in apeareance because they are actually still in the jList)

If, before that, I select an item in my list, then everything is working fine. So my guess would be that the "valueChanged()" method from my listener is doing something that I don't do myself.

Here is my list initialisation, which I call at the start of the program:

```
public final void initList() {
    jListPaiement.setModel(new MyListModel(ls.getDb().getListePaiements()));
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");  

    jListPaiement.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            MoyenPaiement mp = (MoyenPaiement) ((MyListModel) jListPaiement.getModel()).getElementAt(jListPaiement.getSelectedIndex());
            jTextFieldFF.setText(df.format(mp.getFraisf()));
            jTextFieldFV.setText(df.format(mp.getFraisv() * 100));
            jTextFieldNomP.setText(mp.getNom());
            jTextFieldFF.setVisible(true);
            jTextFieldFV.setVisible(true);
            jTextFieldNomP.setVisible(true);
            jLabel1.setVisible(true);
            jLabel6.setVisible(true);
            jLabel7.setVisible(true);
            jLabel8.setVisible(true);
            jLabel11.setVisible(true);
            jButtonSaveP.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Here is the code from the add button:

```
 private void jButtonAddPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {           
    MoyenPaiement mp = new MoyenPaiement("Nouveau", 0, 0);
    ((MyListModel) jListPaiement.getModel()).addElement(mp);
    jListPaiement.setSelectedValue(mp, true);
    jListPaiement.repaint();
}
```

MyListModel code:

```
public class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {

    ArrayList list;

    public MyListModel(ArrayList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public void addElement(Object o){
        list.add(o);
    }

    public void deleteElement(Object o){
        list.remove(o);
    }

    public void setElement(int i,Object o){
        list.set(i, o);
    }

    public ArrayList getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: After further research, the problem is when I add item to my model.

It comes exactly on the line:

```
((MyListModel) jListPaiement.getModel()).addElement(mp);
```

Even if I add a simple string such as:

```
((MyListModel) jListPaiement.getModel()).addElement("String");
```

The problem still occurs.

Comment: can you provide a better code example? I don't see where you initialize `jButtonSaveP` or how you use `jButtonAddPActionPerformed`

Comment: The implementation of `MyListModel` might be of interest since this might interfere with your list, e.g. not provide the correct elements upon repainting.

Comment: I use the netbeans design interface to make my GUI so my buttons are initialized automatically in the `initComponent()`.
`jButtonSaveP` is the button i use to save my edit. It's not my add button and using this button or not doesn't make a difference to my problem.
`jButtonAddPActionPerformed` is used when I click on my button.. Not sure what you mean here sorry..
The `jButtonAddPActionPerformed`

Comment: I would be guessing that this is where you get the error. The `jListPaiement does not recognize `mp` on this line: `jListPaiement.setSelectedValue(mp, true);`

Comment: @Thomas is right, `MyListModel` would be of interest

Comment: Can you try moving all those calls to `setVisible` out of  `valueChanged`? It doesn't make sense there and it might be the actual cause for your problem (I'm not sure I understand your problem/situation correctly, so this is just a guess).

Comment: The thing is, its exactly something in the `valueChanged()`that seems to make it work. Because if i click on my add button without going in the `valueChanged()`method is when my display is not correct.

Comment: Added MyListModel code in the main question for better display.
Sorry this is my first time posting a question..

Comment: How do you initialize ls on this line? `jListPaiement.setModel(new MyListModel(ls.getDb().getListePaiements()));`

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with the initialization there and `jListPaiement.setSelectedValue(mp, true);` can't find the element mp. But your code example is not detailed enough to say if that's the cause

Comment: ls is initialized in the constructor of my class.
`    LoadSave ls;
    ImageIcon logoImg = new ImageIcon();

    public Parameters(final LoadSave ls) {
        initComponents();
        this.ls = ls;
        initList();
} `
The element mp is initialized correctly and added correctly to the list.
If I display via a system.err.print my jList, I can see all the item, but in my GUI it doesn't show anymore after i clicked on my add button.
When I start my program, it shows correctly, but after I click on my add button, it disapear (from the GUI, but not from the model/jList)

Comment: Actually, its only the add button that makes the display in the GUI disappear, even if I select an item in the list before, clicking my add button "deletes" the display of my jList..

Comment: @Thomas I tried anyway to remove all the `setVisible`but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Look in detail what happens on this line and if you initialize `jListPaiement` correctly with the right data.

```
jListPaiement.setModel(new MyListModel(ls.getDb().getListePaiements()));
```

Seems like on this line `setSelectedValue()` can't find the element `mp`

```
jListPaiement.setSelectedValue(mp, true);
```

Comment: jListPaiement gets the correct data, because when the program starts, it display the correct item.
It's only after I click the add button that the display changes.
I'm not sure what you mean when you say that `setSelectedValue()` can't find `mp` since it is initialized just before.
`MoyenPaiement mp = new MoyenPaiement("Nouveau", 0, 0);
        ((MyListModel) jListPaiement.getModel()).addElement(mp);
        jListPaiement.setSelectedValue(mp, true); `

Comment: If you call `setSelectedValue()` with an element not in the list (or null) the selected index should be set to -1 (i.e. nothing is selected). The list should still be displayed correctly.

Comment: That's my point yes, i tried anyway to remove the `setSelectedValue()` and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
Rather than using my own List Model, I used DefaultListModel and everything works fine. It's been long time since i worked on this project and I don't remember why i chose to make my own list model class.

Even tough it works now, I still don't understand what was missing in my own class (MyListModel) that made it not working..